# How to retrieve a count of followers not currently following back with tweepy?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I want to get a number of the accounts not following me back on twitter. I would like it to look something like this:

(number) : Accounts currently not following back.

Unfollow users? y/n

unfollowing taylorswift13...etc

This is what I have so far:

```
followers = api.followers_ids(SCREEN_NAME)
friends = api.friends_ids(SCREEN_NAME)


notFollowing = friends not in followers
print (len(notFollowing), " : Accounts not following back")

def unfollowMain():
unfollowMain = raw_input("Unfollow users? y/n\n")
if unfollowMain == "y":
    for f in friends:
        if f not in followers:
            print "Unfollowing {0}".format(api.get_user(f).screen_name)
            api.destroy_friendship(f)
else:
    print("Exiting...")
    sys.exit()

unfollowMain()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `notFollowing` list can be created a few different ways.  The first two only call the API twice; once for `followers`, once for `friends`.  The third method should be used for checking "one-off" relationships, because each time you call it, it exhausts your rate-limit.

First, a one-liner, using list comprehension:

```
notFollowing = [friend for friend in friends if friend not in followers]
```

Second, same result, but slower:

```
notFollowing = []
for friend in friends:
    if friend not in followers:
        notFollowing.append(friend)
```

The third one is a call to the API method [`api.exists_friendship(user_a,user_b)`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.exists_friendship).

Some advice on the `unfollowMain()` function:

1. Originally you were unnecessarily using a nested for loop to check for friendship status.  Now that you have created `notFollowing`, just loop through that once, and unfollow each one.
2. Each time this is executed `api.get_user(f).screen_name)` you exhaust, one of your rate-limits, I think you get 180 for every 15 minutes.  So if you imagine your `len(notFollowing) > 180` then your program will crash with an Error.  For this reason it's best to work with batches with the tweepy [`Cursor`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html).

Sample Code:

```
followers = api.followers_ids(SCREEN_NAME)  # still only need your followers ids

friends = []
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, user_id=SCREEN_NAME).items():  
    friends.append(friend)  # friend is now a User object, print one to see what's in it.

notFollowing = [friend for friend in friends if friend.id not in followers] # note friend.id
print (len(notFollowing), " : Accounts not following back")

def unfollowMain():
    unfollowMain = raw_input("Unfollow users? y/n\n")
    if unfollowMain == "y":
        for f in notFollowing: # now f is a User obejct from above
            print "Unfollowing {0}".format(f.screen_name) # now you can access the User's screen_name
            api.destroy_friendship(f.id)
        else:
            print("Exiting...")
            sys.exit()

unfollowMain()
```

This should save you A LOT of rate limit headaches!

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful

Comment: No problem, it was good practice to work through.  If any solutions answer your question [please accept the best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).